Conjugacy classes in a subgroup. Solution to problem makes no intuitive sense
Problem: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\leq G$ of index 2. Show that if $x\in H$ has $m$ conjugates in $G$, then $x$ has either $m$ or $m/2$ conjugates in $H$.
My Solution (or attempt): The size of the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$ is known to be $[G:C_G(x)]$. Since $|G/H|=2$ (and say $G=H\cup gH$), $H$ is normal and it's easy to show that $C_H(x)$ is normal in $C_G(x)$, then
$$m=[G:C_G(x)] = \frac{[G:C_H(x)]}{[C_G(x):C_H(x)]} = \frac{[G:H][H:C_H(x)]}{[C_G(x):C_H(x)]} =2\frac{[H:C_H(x)]}{[C_G(x):C_H(x)]}.$$
Now, suppose that $C_G(x)=C_H(x)$, that is, all the conjugacy classes are also in $H$, then $[C_G(x):C_H(x)] =1$ and $[H:C_H(x)]=m/2$. Suppose that there is an element $a\in C_G(x)$ such that $a\not\in C_H(x)$, that is, $a\not\in H$, then $a\in gH$, furthermore, if $b\in C_G(x)$ and $b\not\in gH$ then $b\in H$ and $b\in C_H(x)$, therefore if $C_G(x)\neq C_H(x)$, $[C_G(x):C_H(x)]=2$ and $[H:C_H(x)]=m$.
Now, this makes ABSOLUTELY NO SENSE, if $C_G(x)=C_H(x)$ it means that all the conjugacy classes of $x$ in $G$ are made by elements in $H$ and we should have that $[H:C_H(x)]=m$ aswell, but no. Surely I've made a mistake somewhere but I can't find it

I corrected an error near the beginning.   You can always roll it back if you want.

So... you prefer to yell at people  rather than emphasize?

Why would the centralizers being equal mean all conjugates are obtainable by conjugating by elements of $H$?
It's the opposite: if $gxg^{-1}=hxh^{-1}$, then $h^{-1}g$ centralizes $x$, hence lies in $C_G(x)=C_H(x)\subseteq H$, hence $h^{-1}g\in H$, so $g\in H$. In particular, any $g\in G-H$ gives you a conjugate that you cannot obtain via conjugation by elements of $H$.

Couldn't there be $y$ outside of $H$ that centralizes $x?$

@softtostadaburrito Not if we are assuming that $C_G(x)=C_H(x)$.

Oops,  glossed right over that first paragraph.

Ah! I was totally thinking about it the wrong way, ty
